# Xpath test with namespace

Tags: xml, testing, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

In the following example 1 to access to the value *Vdd* Units of the *DS2438* I can use the following syntax:

- `(//*[local-name() = 'Vdd'])[2]` to find `5.550000` and
- `(//*[local-name() = 'Vdd'])[1]` to find `4.280000`.

Each `<owd_DS2438>` is linked to a physical captor, each one of which is identified by the unique ID `<ROMId>`. The position in the XML file can change.

Question : how can I find the same value in the 2 following examples for a specific `<ROMId>` using a XPATH?

**Example 1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DeviceName>OWServer_v2-Enet</DeviceName>
    <HostName>EDSOWSERVER2</HostName>
    <MACAddress>00:04:A3:F8:62:7B</MACAddress>
    <DateTime>2014-09-06 01:02:39</DateTime>
    <owd_DS2438 Description="Smart battery monitor">
        <Name>DS2438</Name>
        <ROMId>C100000140ABC126</ROMId>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">20.9375</Temperature>
        <Vdd Units="Volts">4.280000</Vdd>
        <Vad Units="Volts">10.230000</Vad>
    </owd_DS2438>
    <owd_DS2438 Description="Smart battery monitor">
        <Name>DS2438</Name>
        <ROMId>C100000140ABC127</ROMId>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">20.9375</Temperature>
        <Vdd Units="Volts">5.550000</Vdd>
        <Vad Units="Volts">10.230000</Vad>
    </owd_DS2438>
</Devices-Detail-Response>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.embeddeddatasystems.com/schema/owserver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DeviceName>OWServer_v2-Enet</DeviceName>
    <HostName>EDSOWSERVER2</HostName>
    <MACAddress>00:04:A3:F8:62:7B</MACAddress>
    <DateTime>2014-09-06 01:02:39</DateTime>
    <owd_DS2438 Description="Smart battery monitor">
        <Name>DS2438</Name>
        <ROMId>C100000140ABC127</ROMId>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">20.9375</Temperature>
        <Vdd Units="Volts">5.550000</Vdd>
        <Vad Units="Volts">10.230000</Vad>
    </owd_DS2438>
    <owd_DS2438 Description="Smart battery monitor">
        <Name>DS2438</Name>
        <ROMId>C100000140ABC126</ROMId>
        <Temperature Units="Centigrade">20.9375</Temperature>
        <Vdd Units="Volts">4.280000</Vdd>
        <Vad Units="Volts">10.230000</Vad>
    </owd_DS2438>
</Devices-Detail-Response>
```

thanks in advance
Stephane

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the same approach with `local-name()` you could use the xpath expression

```
//*[local-name() = 'owd_DS2438' and *[local-name() = 'ROMId'] = 'C100000140ABC127']/*[local-name() = 'Vdd']/text()
```

to select a specific value by *ROMId*.

However, from the context of your question it is not clear to me why you need to ignore namespaces. It may be more practical not to ignore them. In this case the xpath would simplify to

```
//owd_DS2438[ROMId = 'C100000140ABC127']/Vdd/text()
```

which is much more readable (IMHO). This will usually require, however, that you register the default name space in your xpath tool/library.